# Android DialogFragment

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте! 
Как вернуть данные из DialogFragment?

Варианты, что делать все там и ничего не возвращать-не подходит.

Comment: Мария, вообще-то непонятно, что именно Вы хотите вернуть. Создайте callback и вызывайте его, когда хотите вернуть данные.

Comment: @Lucky_spirit, а есть разница какие данные возвращать? 2интовые переменные например.

Comment: @Мария_1 разницы какие данные передавать нет, просто определите их как параметры методов callback'a

Answer (score 1):

Ответ был в комментарии к вашему вопросу(создать callback), а тут приведу пример кода:

```
public class PictureGettedOptionsDialog extends DialogFragment
...
public void setGetImageUriListener(GetImageUriListener listener){
    this.listener = listener;
}
public interface GetImageUriListener {
public void getUri(Uri returnedImageUri);
}
```

внутри в диалоге, где-нибудь

```
if( listener != null )
        listener.getUri(imageUri);
```

ну и естесно при создании диалога вызываете setGetImageUriListener(GetImageUriListener listener)

Answer (score 0):

Activity с фрагментом общается через интерфейс.
Например фрагмент:

```java
public class TheFragment extends DialogFragment {

    // Внутри фрагмента создаём интерфейс для
    // взаимодействия с Activity
    // Эти методы нужно реализовать в Activity
    public interface TheFragmentListener {
        public void onTheFragmentBtnXClick();
        public void onTheFragmentBtnYClick(String url, String title);
        public void onTheFragmentCancelClick();
    }

    // Создать переменную хранящую Listener
    private TheFragmentListener mListener;

    // Установить Activity в качестве Listener
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (TheFragmentListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            // Если Activity не реализует интерфейс
            // TheFragmentLisener - то выкинуть исключение
            // с сообщением (делать это вовсе не обязательно,
            // достаточно убедиться что реализует, взглянув на
            // свой код)
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement ChanFragmentListener");
        }
    }

    // отключение Activity от прослушивания при отсоединении фрагмента
    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    // теперь при обработке событий просто вызывается
    // соответствующий метод из Activity (из mListener)
    // например для нажатия на кнопу BtnY
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        getView().findViewById(R.id.BtnY)
            .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Если mListener существует,
                    // то вызываем его метод с нужными
                    // нам параметрами
                    if (mListener != null) {
                        mListener.onTheFragmentBtnYClick(
                           "http://x.org",
                           "X Windows Systems");
                    }
                }
            });
    } // конец onActivityCreated

    /* ### логика фрагмента ### */

} // конец фрагмента
```

Теперь в Activity

```
// Внимание на implements
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
                                TheFragment.TheFragmentListener {

    // реализация методов интерфейса
    public void onTheFragmentBtnYClick(String url, String title) {
        // логика метода, данные уже в Activity
    }

    public void onTheFragmentBtnXClick() {};

    public void onTheFragmentCancelClick() {};

    /* тело Activity */

}
```

Вот собственно и вся стратегия. При прикреплении (onAttach) фрагмента в нем из MainActivity создаётся объект TheFragmentListener. Который по сути
и является MainActivity. При нажатии на кнопку событие передаётся от фрагмента к MainActivity вместе с параметрами.

Есть и более простой и брутальный метод. Например в onClick кнопки фрагмента:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).someMethod(args);
}
```

В MainActivity остаётся только реализовать public someMethod:

```
public someMethod(String word) {
    // stuff
};
```

Здесь методом getActivity() получаем активити, преобразуем её к MainActivity и банально вызываем публичный метод.

Если требуется при закрытии фрагмента передать какие-то данные, то можно (как вариант) сохранить их в переменной, а при закрытии фрагмента (например в onDestroy) передать их MainActivity вызвав её метод способом указанным выше.

Answer (score -1):

Вот, все работает только что проверил. Код кстати полностью с документации.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html вот очень поможет, все предельно ясно.

```
 @Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setMessage(R.string.gotostartmess)
           .setPositiveButton(R.string.positive, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                  Log.e(tag, "Возвращаем 1");
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton(R.string.negative, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                  Log.e(tag, "Возвращаем 2");
               }
           });
    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
    return builder.create();
}
```

Логи при positive 
11-09 19:53:09.070: E/dialog(11254): Возвращаем 1

Логи при negative 
11-09 19:53:13.854: E/dialog(11254): Возвращаем 2

Comment: Все было бы хорошо. Но! Мы на клик выводим просто сообщение, но данные то не передаем.... Вопрос именно в том, как вернуть данные в активити, из которой был вызван диалог

Comment: Делаете в классе переменную и её можно возвращать через специальный метод. Вызвали - получили, записали - забрали.

Comment: @nekaneka ну вот передать в диалог данные получилось через setArguments()/getArguments() а как вернуть я так и не нашла

Comment: String dataToReturn = "...";
return dataToReturn;

Comment: @SuperCreeper в каком методе это пишется и как в вызывающей активити эти данные поймать?

Comment: Мария почитайте доки из моего поста, очень внимательно.

Comment: алерт диалог и диалог фрагмент - это не одно и тоже